# How to use flipOnTouch in flutter flip_card conditionally?

Tags: flutter

I am building a card game in flutter.
So far I have a CardBoard widget and a Card widget.
In the Card widget I use the FlipCard widget from flip_card with a provider.
In onFlip: I notice the provider.
FlipCard has a property flipOnTouch. If that is set to false cards can not be flipped.
If I use it like this:

```
onFlip: () {
isFlipped = ref.read(cardProvider.notifier).flipCard(playcard);
print(isFlipped);
},
flipOnTouch: isFlipped,
```

isFlipped prints false, but when clicked the card still flips.
Must the Card widget be a stateful widget?